# Configurable product options – get price difference in brackets

Tags: product, configurable-product, price

I know that a few themes have this by default but my one doesn't, and i just cant get this to work.

I have a configurable Product which has three options with different prices. I want to show the price difference to the linked simple product in brackets. So it should basically look like this:

Price: XX€

(x) option 1 –
( )  option 2 (+ 4,00$) –
( )  option 3 (+ 12,00$)

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display it on view.phtml but you could make this where you want.

$product -> configurable

```
 <?php echo 'Price: ' . $product->getPrice() . '<br>'; ?>

    <?php 
$childs = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts(); 
foreach($childs as $child){
    echo $child->getName() . ' - ' ; 
} 
 ?>
```

this should display what you want, but check that you make a good display with the first and last child to get the correct output.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your effort! I want to display it in configurable.phtml but i get this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in ...default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml on line 49

Comment: It's becouse i miss a ';' before foreach.

I don't know it it will work perfectly, but it's a way to make it like this.